# Is $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{irev}}{T}$ true for non-reversible processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

The German Wikipedia reads

> Das Differential $\mathrm {d} S$  ist nach Clausius bei reversiblen Vorgängen zwischen Zuständen im Gleichgewicht das Verhältnis von übertragener Wärme $\delta Q_{\mathrm {rev} }$ und absoluter Temperatur $T$: $dS=\frac{Q_{\mathrm {rev} }}{T}$

Which translates to

> According to Clausius the differential $\mathrm {d} S$  for reversible processes between equilibirum states is the ratio between transmitted heat $\delta Q_{\mathrm {rev} }$ and absolute temperature $T$: $dS=\frac{Q_{\mathrm {rev} }}{T}$

This formulation seems confusing to me. Why do we need **reversibility**? I do not see why this shouldn't be true for quasi-static irreversible processes. We start at a state of entropy $S_1$ and by some process we reach $S_2$. As the entropy by axiom is path-independent it shouldn't matter weather the path is reversible or not.

**Addendum:** Many people stated in the comments that one can use a reversible process starting and resulting in the same equilibrium state, as the irreversible one. While this is true and an important concept, my question was aimed at the actual heat $\delta Q_{irev}$ that is transferred to the system during a irreversible process.

Related [The actual definition of entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376791/the-actual-definition-of-entropy)

Comment: I think its because they are using the reversible heat Qrev not the heat to actually heat the non-reversible process

Comment: In addition to entropy transferred from the surroundings to the system during a process (which is described by dq/T), in an irreversible process, entropy is generated within the system, which is not accounted for by dq/T.  Therefore, using dq/T for an irreversible process will give the wrong answer for the change in entropy.

Comment: The title of your post should have the subscript $rev$ with $\delta Q$.

Comment: @ChetMiller How do we account for that entropy? I always took the formula in the title as the defintion of entropy and now I'm confused on how it is really defined. It seems like theres some sort of inner degrees of freedom that are triggered during a irreversible process?

Comment: @BobD I changed the title to make more clear what I was asking and added an explanation.

Comment: I see. Regarding the last sentence of the addendum you do realize that irreversible processes can involve no heat transfer at all, correct?

Comment: @BobD Yes.In my head I define a non-reversible process as a process acting on the universe that cannot be undone. If in the example by Wolphram the work would have been saved in a "battery" during the quasi static expansion of the gas, then the process could have been reversed. But we postulate that the free expansion cannot be reversed (empirical). I struggel to fomulate this concept of reversibility in terms of entropy though. I thought that defining the entropy function by $dS=\delta{Q} / T$ and saying $dS_{universe}\geq0$ would do the trick, but as can be seen by the example it does not.

Comment: For an irreversible process, what you need to do is devise an alternate reversible path for the system between the exact same two thermodynamic end states and calculate the integral of dq/T for that path.  That will give you the entropy change for the irreversible path.  For more details on this, including worked examples, see this link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One counterexample is a quasi static irreversible adiabatic free expansion. Here d$S>0$ and d$Q=0$, so the equality is not valid for this irreversible process.

Comment: How would you realize a quasi-static free expansion? By definition of q.s. the gas has to expand in a sequence of equilibria, which is not given in the case of, let's say, spontaneously removing a partition.

Comment: You can still use assume a reversible transfer of heat process to get the entropy change for the irreversible adiabatic free expansion. In that case you can assume a reversible isothermal compression to return the system to its original state before the free expansion. The magnitude of the entropy change for the reversible isothermal compression will equal the entropy change that occurred in the free expansion. $\Delta S$ for the system will be zero when returned to its original state, but the isothermal compression will increase the entropy of the surroundings so that $\Delta S_{TOT}$ >0.

Comment: @Nephente I imagine it as removing a series of partitions very close to each other, so the new volume is incremented in steps

Comment: @BobD I agree with you, and perhaps I misinterpreted the question. It was not if you can find a reversible process to calculate the change in entropy, but if the equation was valid for an irreversible process, which is different to me, that is, use the change in entropy and heat transferred during that specific irreversible process..

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I see your point, it could be viewed that way as well. The equation is, of course, defines entropy change in terms of a reversible transfer of heat. There are many irreversible work processes between two equilibrium states not of which involves any heat transfer. But to determine what the entropy generated is we can assume a process between the states involving a reversible transfer of heat and we will obtain the entropy generated for the irreversible work process.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Indeed you interpreted the question just right.

Comment: Is adiabatic free expansion a quasi-static process? What the "quasi static irreversible adiabatic free expansion” means? Free but  quasi static ?

Comment: @BlueVarious it is an irreversible process, I never meant it to be quasi-static, and it is not required either

Comment: So, what is the  quasi static  of " quasi static irreversible adiabatic free expansion" you means?  Is this a typo?

Comment: @BlueVarious sorry, I read the answer too fast. Yes, I mean that, quasi-static. I did not clarify it, but by that I meant a process in which you open a new compartment that is only differentially larger than the original, and after an infinite number of such processes (that is, mini free expansions) you get the final finite volume you want.

Comment: The questioner's (@TheoreticalMinimum) question contains a lot of confusion. But he/she is asking about whether "dS=δQ_rev/T" holds for "quasi-static but not reversible processes". But your answer is about "examples that are neither quasi-static nor reversible".

Comment: @BlueVarious the process I described is both quasi-static and irreversible, what part makes you think it is not so?

Comment: Irreversible adiabatic free expansion is indeed irreversible. But it is not quasi-static. Because it is not possible to draw the reaction path of irreversible adiabatic free expansion on U-V-N space. It is　via  non-equilibrium state where U, V and N cannot be defined at any time before equilibrium is reached.

Comment: @BlueVarious you should read again my description in the previous comments

Comment: A "quasi-static adiabatic change" is quasi-static and reversible because it is an adiabatic change with constant entropy in the course of the reaction.

Comment: Additionally, "Quasi static irreversible adiabatic free expansion" you wrote is a nonsense concept.

Comment: @BlueVarious A quasi-static process is just a well defined curve in the phase space. This process does not necessarily have to be reversible.

Comment: The issue which I had at the time I asked the question is most likely the same as you do: Many books are imprecise in the definition of irreversible and non-quasi static processes. There is often a lack of a proper definition of "reversibility". Anyways it should not be defined by "quasi-static" as some authors do.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Because both $δQ_{rev}(U,V,N)$ and  $δQ_{rev}(U,V,N)/T$ are  always state quantities, it is possible to calculate them if we record the U,V,N,T,P,μ along the reaction path, even if the reaction is irreversible; of cause we suppose that the reaction path could be written as a smooth curve in the state space, So,  the notion of the "reversible reaction" may be less important, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

> Why do we need reversibility? I do not see why this shouldn't be true
>   for quasi-static irreversible processes.

Although the definition is in terms of a reversible transfer of heat, you are correct that it is not limited to a reversible process, i.e., it applies to an irreversible process as well. Entropy is a state function or property, like internal energy. That means the difference in entropy between two equilibrium states is independent of the path or process between the states.

So if you have an irreversible process taking you between two states you can determine the entropy change of the system by assuming any convenient reversible process between the states. That will give you the entropy change for the *system* for the irreversible process as well since entropy is a state function.

However, if the process is irreversible, entropy is generated by the system. In order to return the system to its original state (perform a cycle) the entropy generated will need to be transferred to the surroundings making the total entropy change (system + surroundings) >0 for a complete cycle. For a reversible cycle the overall entropy change = 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "So if you have an irreversible process taking you between two states you can determine the entropy change of the system by assuming any convenient reversible process between the states." I think it is worth stressing here, for clarity, that, since heat is a path dependant property, the heat transfer on this conveinient reversible path will in general not be the same as the amount of heat transfered on the real physical irriversible process. This means we can't simply plug the measured $\delta Q$ in in place of $dQ_\mathrm{rev}$ and expect to get the right answer

Comment: @BySymmetry "While heat is a path dependent property". First of all, heat is not a property. While heat is path dependent a reversible transfer of heat divided by temperature is not path dependent. If it were, it would be tantamount to saying entropy between equilibrium states is path dependent since $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$. Second of all, I never said you can simply plug in $\delta q$ for $\delta q_{rev}$.  I was responding to the text of the OP's question where the subscript $rev$ is always used and not the title which incorrectly left out the $rev$ subscript.

Comment: I don't think we disagree on anything here. When I say "Heat is a path dependant property" I mean it is a property of a path and not of the system. My comment was trying to emphasise a point rather than imply that anything you said was wrong

Comment: @BySymmetry Got it, no problem. Sorry but when I hear the word property in a thermodynamics discussion it has a specific meaning to me- $U$, $P$. $V$, $T$ etc. that goes beyond the dictionary definition, which I now see is the way you were using it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a comment;

The discussion here seems to confuse two (three) different types of "entropy".

> - If you say that "entropy is a state quantity" this is what is called "exchanged entropy". This is uniquely determined depend on the state (U,V,N), so let's represent this as a mathematical multivariable function $S_{e}(U,V,N)$.
> - If you say that "entropy increases with decreasing irreversible processes", this is called "generated entropy". Let's express this by the symbol $S_{g}$.
> - We define the  $\Delta S_{tot}$ as follows. The  $\Delta S_{tot}$ represents the entropy change in the entire system via the reaction between  the reaction from $(U_1,V_1,N_1)$ to  $(U_2,V_2,N_2)$ ;
>   $$\Delta S_{tot}:=S_{e}(U_2,V_2,N_2)-S_{e}(U_1,V_1,N_1)+S_{g}$$

For more details for the exchanged/generated entropies plesae
[this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=I1Y-CwAAQBAJ&pg=PR12&lpg=PR12&dq=%22generated+entropy%22+%E2%80%9Dexchanged+entropy%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=7Um5RTBtsn&sig=ACfU3U2AdBKtxt9xUB-9OYWpjD4rRqgesw&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFls3ypObrAhUCIIgKHdLvCIAQ6AEwAnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22generated%20entropy%22%20%E2%80%9Dexchanged%20entropy%E2%80%9D&f=false) might be helpful.

Note that since $S_{g}$ is not a state quantity, $S_{tot}$ is not a state quantity either.

This Q&A also includes other confusion.
**The concept of "whether this reaction can be written as a curve in U-V-N space or not" and the concept of "whether this reaction is reversible or not" are different concepts.** In this sense, the reaction paths can be classified from the two different view point; "writable/unwritable" and "reversible/irreversible".

From the "writable/unwritable" viewpoint, the reaction paths can be classified into two types;

> - Reaction that cannot be written as smooth curves in the state space(U-V-N space): e.g., "adiabatic free expansion
> - A reaction that can be written as a smooth curve in the state space: the quasi-static process is pseudo-this.

The viewpoint of "reversible/irreversible", is too confused, so, I will omit the definition of this. However, there are four kinds of combinations:

- writable and reversible,
- writable and irreversible,
- unwritable and reversible, and
- unwritable and irreversible.

Probably the third one is an abstract nonsense (Such an example probably does not exist.)

Furthermore, "adiabatic free expansion" has　also been confused with "quasi static adiabatic expansion. " In order to be "quasi static", the piston must be controlled; move a little bit, applying the brakes. This is no longer free expansion. In the process of braking the piston, an external force is applied to the system.

Comment: Bravo.. Excellent answer. If you don't mind could you see the thermodynamics questions on my account? I would really appreciate if you were to answer it.

Comment: By the way, it would be awesome if you could give some further reading/citations to your post

Comment: I don't know if I can answer that right now, but I'll try. Where do I find that question? Give me the link.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579414/is-q-dependent-on-the-epsilon-which-is-choose-in-the-expression-gibbs-f

I am really struggling with this one

Answer (score 0):

[Clausius' theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem) is about **heat exchange with quasistatic volume change**. When the volume is changed non quasistatically (as in free expansion or when some irreversible work is done), the question takes a different meaning. In Clausius' approach the only changes in entropy are caused by heat exchange, not irreversible volume change.

Orginally, Clausius' point about irreversibility is the following. When a system exhanges heat with the surroundings (a heat bath), we have:

- the heat transfer is reversible if and only if $T_{surr}=T_{system}$
- then, $\Delta S_{system} = \frac{Q}{T_{surr}}$
- otherwise $\Delta S_{system} > \frac{Q}{T_{surr}}$

Important: "reversible/irreversible" here applies to the heat exchange, meaning to "system + surroundings". Seeing the process as reversible/irreversible for the system only does not make sense and leads to confusions.

Writing just $T$ is ambigous. Is it the temperature of the system or the temperature the surroundings? The fact is, when heat is not transfered reversibly, the temperature of the system usually does not even exist, since a gradient appears inside the system and it does not have a uniform temperature. Assuming the gradient spreads over a small volume (negligible energy), we may say the system still has constant temperature almost everywhere. Then we have $\Delta S_{system} = \frac{Q}{T_{system}}$.

As a conclusion, $T$ is meaningful for reversible processes, and then it is both the temperature of the system and the surroundings. Otherwise, $T_{system}$ does not exist during the process and $\Delta S_{system} > \frac{Q}{T_{surr}}$. When the temperature is near uniform inside the system, then $\Delta S_{system} = \frac{Q}{T_{system}}$, even for an irreversible process.