# Is $ Q $ dependent on the $ \epsilon$ which is choose in the expression Gibb's free energy of a chemical reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

In this lecture by mit ocw(*), Moungi Bawendi states that we can have **some change** in our **chemical system** containing reactants and products by **scaled by** some $ \epsilon$ amount. Using this set up and the equation which gives chemical potential as a function of pressure (**) he derives the $\Delta G$ as a function of $ \epsilon$ as shown below:

$$ \mu_{i} (T , P_{tot} )  = u_{i}^{o} (T) + RT \ln \frac{P}{P_o}$$

and, with the expression for $ \Delta G $ in terms of chemical potentials:

$$ \Delta G  = \sum_{i=prods} \mu_i \nu_i - \sum_{i= reacts} \mu_i \nu_i$$

He gets,

$$ \Delta G(\epsilon) = \epsilon [ \Delta G^{o} + RT \ln \frac{ (P_d)^{v_d} (P_c)^{v_c} }{ (P_b)^{v_b} (P_a)^{v_a} }]$$

Now, this expression I have a few questions about:

- Is the **pressure ratio term** on the right hand side **dependent** on  $\epsilon$?
- **How** does one ****correctly interpret** the final equation** ? Is it related to calculus of variations ? I ask this because it looks very similar ot the derivation of fundamental theorem of calculus of variations [(found here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#:%7E:text=The%20calculus%20of%20variations%20is,functions%20to%20the%20real%20numbers.&text=Many%20important%20problems%20involve%20functions%20of%20several%20variables.)

---

*: [Reference video](https://youtu.be/Cc2l1QTTZA4?t=2585)

**: page-4 of [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-60-thermodynamics-kinetics-spring-2008/lecture-notes/5_60_lecture13.pdf) from mit ocw